# Increment a item in a child in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My firebase realtime database]

I want to increment the item **l** by 1 when the *like* button in my android app is clicked.

Only way I know to do that is first retrieve the value of **l** by a *ValueEventListener* and then increment that value(from app) and update the **l** in database to that value.

I think that may occur many problems when 2 or more users trying to increment the same value same time concurrently.

*So, please give me a proper solution to do that without errors.*

Comment: The proper solution for this is to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). I recommend that you read the documentation, give it a try, and report back if you're having problems implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is called concurrency or parallelism (depending on how exact you want to be with the term).

You have to use a transaction, a transaction is a method that will create a sort of *bridge* with the data to modify, this *communication* will remain until the computations are completed.

So you get the data and then add one, then modify the data. Since this is in real-time more than one user doing it at the same time will most likely have no negative effect (seriously real-time database is computed in less than milliseconds, the delay is because of the internet speed).

This is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). Transaction sounds like a generic name, for any data exchange, but is not, is a method.

One more thing worth to mention, if you need to do something on the UI or using an interface callback, you have to do it in the `onComplete` method.

Comment: ThankYou..you can see in the image above that I had name the child in an incremental procedure..I did it by retreiving the **i** value of last index and add 1 to it and *add the new child to database by that i value*...But that process can't implement by firebase transactions...can you give me a solution for that

Comment: increase the child in the transaction then in the onComplete create the other

Answer (score 0):

There's a new method `ServerValue.increment()`in firebase Java SDK

It's better for performance and cheaper since no round trip is required.

API Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

You can increment or decrement with it (`1` or `-1`).